# Possibility to `unfold 4 identical lines skipped` in reviewing edits

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I was recently reviewing a suggested edit where the only modification was one symbol ($\in$ to become $\subset$) in the first line of the post. Most of the question was hidden and replaced by the text `4 identical lines skipped`.

Because of unusual notation and phrasing altogether, the first line was actually not enough to make sure that the correction was relevant, so I clicked on the `4 identical lines skipped` to unfold the hidden parts - except that you don't have that option.

So I suggest upgrading this `4 identical lines skipped` into a button

> `unfold 4 identical lines skipped`.

I know that it's possible to `ctrl`+`click` on the link of the OP to open it in a new tab, but I figured the above suggestion would be more user-friendly, especially because if you forget the `ctrl`, you open the OP in the current tab and then you can't necessarily come back to this particular review and your efforts thinking about that review are gone to the bin.

Comment: A similar feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Make “x identical lines skipped” expandable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174301).